# Python XML comparison

Tags: python, xml

I have 2 files each with a list of items which all have 3 properties. What is the quickest way to compare these files and list the differences, i.e. the items that are not in both files.

For the items to be the same, all 3 properties have to agree. Also the files were in XML.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks! I tried looping through the first set of items and within that loop compare the name with each item in the second set. If there's no match then continue, else go to compare the first property. Do the same thing again but for the first property. If this matches, then compare the final two. If it gets that far and the last two match, then they are the same. But i don't know where to output the ones there are no match for.

Comment: May be you can post the code you are describing in your question. Use the `edit` button to do so. It will be easier to get some help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic algorithm:

- generate a set of tuples `(name, price, expiryDate)` for the source
- generate a set of tuples `(name, price, expiryDate)` for the destination
- use [set methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) to find intersection / difference / union etc.

You already have most of the pieces in place...

Answer (score 0):

I would use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) to do this.